# Can't resize view in interface builder

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode, interface-builder

I want to do a Tab Bar Controller as "main window" and I want to do another view, for another button.
How do I resize the second View so I can like "put" it over the Tab Bar, like the guide want me to?

From 360x460 to 360x411, but interface builder wont let me to change the size.
Thanks!

Comment: You have need to make tabBar Application.

Comment: Don't change the size of the other view, just shift the UI elements so that they don't show up behind the bar. Or you can set the UITabBar to scale it's subviews.

Answer (score 5):

I assume that when you say that Xcode doesn't allow to change the size you mean the interface builder.

If my assumption is right you should change the "Simulated User Interface" of your Viewcontroller in interface builder. Select the root view and set `Bottom Bar` to Tab Bar in the attributes inspector. **This changes the size of the view to 320x411 without touching the raw size attributes.**

[image: Interface Builder]

---

EDIT: I wouldn't recomment it, but if you really want to change the size of the view in interface builder, you have to disable all elements from the simulated user interface. 
I guess it's the simulated status bar that prevents you from resizing the view.

Comment: Okay, I was following this guide at 07.05 http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LBnPfAtswgw&feature=related Please look at it and tell me what to do! (angel)

Comment: Thanks dude, but I put "Tab Bar" as Bottom Bar and it worked! She used a old version of Xcode.

Comment: that's the problem with most tutorials you find on the web, most of them are horribly outdated. Btw, you should click the checkmark next to my answer if it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You usually just place the new View Controller in a tab of the Tab Bar controller. The view will be resized to fit the space available.